# I want to count number of feature executed in serenity framework

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I am using serenity framework. I just want to count number of feature executed.
I am able to count scenarios but getting stuck while counting executed feature files. Please let me know if having any idea.

Comment: what effort have your done so far?

Comment: I was putting featurecount++ into @beforeClass but as it is printing 1 because it will execute at once only.
I am not getting any other way where I can put it

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please, the question needs to provide more information.